# Iterate through a Future Map in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How do I iterate through a map that has been returned from a Future function in flutter? `forEach` doesn't work on Future Maps.

Essentially, is there any way to convert a Future Map to a normal Map object?

Comment: Hi There. you should elaborate your use case. Where are you getting the Future from ? What are you trying to convert it into ? Post sample code.

Comment: I am consuming an API and thus the result is a Future Map. I want to iterate through the map and show the individual keys and values on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Future<Map>` objects can be converted to `Map` objects by awaiting them.

For example:

```
final Future<Map<String, dynamic>> mapFuture = mapApi.get();
final Map<String, dynamic> exampleMap = await mapFuture;
```

All of this should be the part of an `async` function.

Example of an async function:

```
Future<void> asyncFunction() async {}
```

When you get a `Map` object after awaiting you can call the forEach function on that `Map`.

This may help: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: I want to do the conversion inside a function that returns a widget list for the listview widget. So if I make that function async, it wlill return a Future List and so there will be a problem. Is there any other way?

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You could use a `FutureBuilder` widget. It helps with awaiting for futures that your UI depends on. You can find more info here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html